# Python: How to iterate over files changing their names in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a beginner with Python, and I come from MATLAB.
What I need to do is create a loop with years from 2000 to 2016. I have a directory with a lot of files, whose filenames contain these years, like "file_2006".
How can I create a loop to open the files for specific years? In MATLAB I would do it like:

```
for i=2000:2016
year=num2str(i);
filename=['file_' year];
X=cdfread(filename); % and then some operations with X that I read here
end
```

But is it possible to do it in Python? Thank you!

Comment: `filename = 'file_{}'.format(2000)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
for year in range(2000,2017):
    file_name = "file_{year}".format(year=year)
    with open(file_name) as file:
        file_data = file.read()
```

see the documentation about how to work with files here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: `file_name = f'year_{year}'` syntax also works if using Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do, just use format or %s like this:

```
for item in range(2000,2016):
    file_name = "%s" % item
    print (print file_name)
    # or do what you want
```